# How does the processor know the breakpoints?

Tags: c, debugging, exception, assembly, operating-system

Lets consider this very simple program:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main () 
{
    int num1=4, num2=5;
    printf("Welcome\n");
    printf("num1 + num2 = %d\n", num1+num2);
    return 0;
}
```

When looking on the generated assembly code using `gcc -S prog.c`:

```
    .file   "p.c"
    .def    ___main;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .section .rdata,"dr"
LC0:
    .ascii "Welcome\0"
LC1:
    .ascii "num1 + num2 = %d\12\0"
    .text
    .globl  _main
    .def    _main;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
_main:
LFB10:
    .cfi_startproc
    pushl   %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 8
    .cfi_offset 5, -8
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    .cfi_def_cfa_register 5
    andl    $-16, %esp
    subl    $32, %esp
    call    ___main
    movl    $4, 28(%esp)
    movl    $5, 24(%esp)
    movl    $LC0, (%esp)
    call    _puts
    movl    28(%esp), %edx
    movl    24(%esp), %eax
    addl    %edx, %eax
    movl    %eax, 4(%esp)
    movl    $LC1, (%esp)
    call    _printf
    call    _getchar
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    .cfi_restore 5
    .cfi_def_cfa 4, 4
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
LFE10:
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 5.3.0"
    .def    _puts;  .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _printf;    .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
    .def    _getchar;   .scl    2;  .type   32; .endef
```

I know that the CPU see's the assembled code that the compiler generated for it, what I don't understand is how the program stops at the `breakpoint` that the user set ? why doesn't the CPU continue running the program ? what and how does that happens ?
I mean, why would it stop after fetching an instruction ?

I am a bit confused about it, is it Code::Blocks caring for this or whatever program user is using ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The debugger takes care of this. It either overwrites your program with a software breakpoint instruction (`int3`) or by setting up a hardware assisted breakpoint.

Comment: How does the CPU know `addl` is an addition? How what to do with the `ret` instruction?

Comment: @Olaf he can't see in the generated code the command that causes the program to halt. This has nothing to do with his understanding of `addl` or `ret` I think.

Comment: @TonyTannous: If you know how breakpoints in RAM are used, you know it very well does.

Comment: @Olaf breakpoints in RAM ? I didn't understand sorry.

Comment: @TonyTannous: Beakpoints in ROM work differently.

Comment: The answer varies amongst processors.

Comment: @chux intel x86

Comment: 'why would it stop after fetching an instruction ?' - it doesn't.  It stops when that instruction is about to be executed.  Modern processors often fetch instructions that are not executed.

Comment: [See this answer for a discussion of how debuggers do this on x86 (in the context of Visual Studio, but not exclusive to that environment)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135561/how-does-adding-a-run-time-breakpoint-in-visual-studio-work/41179799#41179799)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Most modern instruction sets include a `breakpoint` exception, used to allow debuggers to insert breakpoints in a program's code by temporarily replacing the relevant program instruction with the special software interrupt instruction. On the x86/x86-64 ISA, this instruction is "interrupt vector 3" (aka `int3`), which is usually emitted as the single-byte instruction `0xcc`.

An important thing to note about breakpoint instructions is that they generally must be at least as small as the smallest possible instruction on the ISA. There are a few reasons for this. Some ISAs require minimum alignments for instructions; a shorter instruction will typically have less strict alignment requirements. Additionally, replacing some instruction with a longer one means that you are likely to overwrite a later instruction. This might not be a big deal in single-threaded applications, but in multithreaded applications, it is a show-stopper. Consider, for example, what might happen if you replace a short instruction at the end of an optional branch with a longer one, and another running thread skips the branch.

In other cases, such a special instruction may not exist. On hardware platforms lacking a specific breakpoint instruction, special hardware registers are sometimes provided to cause the processor to trap when it attempts to access a particular location in memory. These registers are typically rather limited in number, so when debugging with numerous breakpoints, a dedicated breakpoint instruction is extremely useful.

When you start your program in a debugger and add a software-enabled breakpoint, what typically happens is something like the following:

The debugger loads the program into memory and provides you some input prompt. You tell the debugger to add a breakpoint. It may use some information to figure out where in memory your breakpoint actually corresponds to the in-memory representation of the program. The debugger then decodes the instruction at that address (because it generally wants to replace the whole instruction) and replaces 
it (in memory) with the breakpoint instruction. You then tell the debugger to execute / continue executing the program.

When the processor encounters this instruction, it generates a trap. This trap is delivered as an interrupt to the operating system, which notices that the trap is intended to debug the program. The OS knows which program is being executed (therefore also who is executing it) -- so it may do some permission checks to make sure the user debugging the application is actually allowed to do so at this point. If all looks good, the OS notifies the debugger that a breakpoint was encountered, and it tells you that it stopped.

This isn't a universal explanation. Significant OS support is required for the above to be true. On Linux and the BSDs, most of this functionality is exposed through the `ptrace(2)` syscall (which allows reading and replacing instructions, as well as single-stepping them). While POSIX-compliant, OS X does not implement `ptrace(2)` and instead provides various Mach ports for this. Windows has something else entirely.

On embedded systems, special hardware ports (like [JTAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JTAG)) might be supplied to allow introspection at a hardware level, allowing the development of an external debugger, which "speaks" directly to the hardware using JTAG.

Comment: ?? modern debuggers use internal hardware breakpoint registers.  Software breakpoints are no longer useful due to internal pipelining issues and multithreading problems.

Comment: hardware looking for an address has the same problem as replacing the memory with a breakpoint instruction with respect to the pipe.  old fashioned debugging is...old fashioned...more than in the past you are going to interfere with things that you need to not interfere with to debug, stop/change the flow of code due to a breakpoint or by single stepping, etc you are changing the behavior, sometimes that doesnt matter, sometimes that does, depends on the bug...

Comment: replacing an instruction in memory is one solution, having something in the cpu or chip that watches for an address or instruction or some mechanism and stops the core without having the replace the instruction is another solution.  The replace the instruction solution allows for a near infinite number of breakpoints, the internal on chip debugger solution generally is limited to some relatively small number of breakpoints at any one time.

Comment: Nitpick: _the debugger will insert in the generated code_ -- "insert" is ambiguous here... it saves the first byte of the target instruction and temporarily overwrites with `int3`.  "Insert" implies shifting instructions to make room for the interrupt instruction.

Comment: @thingy That statement is clearly false; what would a debugger do if you had more than 4 breakpoints set? What are the "internal pipelining issues" that make software breakpoints "no longer useful"? It is guaranteed that, regardless of pipelining and out-of-order execution, instructions will always be retired in order, and thus appear as if they were executed serially. Also, what are the "multithreading problems", other than those inherent to debugging multithreaded code? Hardware breakpoint registers *might* be used, but software breakpoints are still viable and commonplace.

Comment: @TonyTannous It might be worth noting that `int 3` could be `0xcd03` or `0xcc`, and why a debugger would use `0xcc` instead. In particular, that the size of breakpoint instruction must necessarily be <= the smallest instruction supported by the processor, and why this must be true. Possibly also worth noting that `int 3` is specific to the x86/x86-64 ISA.

Comment: @dho edit my answer, I think your explanation will be better than my limited one. I will approve the editting.

Comment: I went a bit overboard, but HTH.