# How to calculate the address of where to insert a dynamic breakpoint

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I'll be using Visual Studio for C/C++ as a framework because that's the debugger I'm most interested in.

When I set a breakpoint in the code, it becomes "immediately" active even if the code is already running. As far as I understand, this is done by Read/WriteProcessMemory. What I don't understand is how you get the exact memory address that you write the int 3 instruction into.

For static breakpoints, it's easy because then the compiler could essentially parse the breakpoint alongside the source code, and insert the int 3 instruction as a natural part of code gen. But with dynamic breakpoints I don't see how you can map a breakpoint on an arbitrary line of source code into the correct address for the executable as it is running. How do you calculate it?

Comment: What are those dynamic breakpoints that you speak of? Also see the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41135561

Comment: Yes, that was the question where everything BUT the very thing I was wondering about was answered . Take for instance this quote from the accepted answer: "So what it does instead is insert the INT instruction (0xCC) at the requested location, writing over whatever instruction is currently there." My question is: how do we, in all cases, figure out where the requested location is in the executables memory from the source code?

Comment: We have .PDB file for that. It has machine location of every line of code.

Comment: Yes, but how are PDB files (and any general notion of accomplishing the same thing as PDB files do) constructed? What are the algorithms, and what should a compiler generating debug files in practical terms do to accomplish it?

Comment: That is a pretty broad question. Start with the description of [PDB format](https://llvm.org/docs/PDB/index.html). Also, google for <pdb debug format>.

Comment: I know that it's a pretty broad question, so I was hoping for a pretty comprehensive, but specific, answer. "Read this documentation" isn't helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does adding a run-time breakpoint in Visual Studio work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41135561/how-does-adding-a-run-time-breakpoint-in-visual-studio-work)

Comment: @GuidedHacking No, because it doesn't describe how to construct a debugging file so that the mapping from a dynamically inserted breakpoint in a running program in the debugger hits the correct machine code.